# Crop List images and preserve text

Tags: html, css

I have a Menu `ul` `li` List with images and text.

> I'm not able to edit the HTML, only modify it with CSS.

[image: visible]

---

Using CSS I want to crop the images to fit a max width/height, but preserve the `span` text Title.

[image: crop]

---

The problem is the way the HTML is nested, `overflow: hidden` cuts off the `span` text.

[image]

---

https://jsfiddle.net/vdL79psL

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 120px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li img {
  max-width: 150px;
}

.title {
  overflow: visible; /* does not work */
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test1">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LRtmiFT.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2STzkq5.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test3">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/grvjWRW.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea would be to apply the overflow on the `a` element then make the `span` to be positioned relatively to `li` (using `position:absolute`) and not to `a` so it won't get affected by the overflow:

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em;
  position: relative; /*relative here !*/
  margin-bottom:35px; /*To consider the space taken by the title*/
}

.menu li a {
  display: block;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: hidden; /*overflow here */
}

.menu li img {
  max-width: 150px;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test1">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LRtmiFT.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2STzkq5.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test3">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/grvjWRW.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may helps you

```css
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
   vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
   max-height: 120px;
position: relative;
}

.menu li img {
  width: 150px;
}

.title {
overflow: visible;
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 999;
background: #fff;
display: block;
right: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test1">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LRtmiFT.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 1</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test2">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2STzkq5.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="item">
    <a href="/test3">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/grvjWRW.jpg">
      <span class="title">Title 3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This won't crop the image but it will shrink it

Comment: I have been updated the code now check it, It works perfectly now